# Google map overlapping of markers in the same locations and not visible to user

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have trouble with my google map script where the markers on a same location overlapped and not visible to user. I tried to edit my script using OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier available in this link https://github.com/jawj/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier. But overlapping issue exist.No improvement occured.

The below function binds a popup window with marker.I have edited the function to remove overlapping of markers in the same location using OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier.

```
function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, contentString)
    {
        var oms = new OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier(map);
        oms.addMarker(marker);
        oms.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() {
        infoWindow.setContent(contentString);
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
        $("#tabs").tabs();
         });
    }

    // highlighting a marker
```

Below is the jsfiddle link of my edited google map.Please show me where iam doing wrong.

http://jsfiddle.net/7AKuX/11/

Comment: I don't even see the map working, have you tried to use the Google Maps v3 API's Cluster function? It's used to group the pins in a same location: https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/toomanymarkers?hl=en

Comment: Does this fiddle working??? It shows error with markers[i] = marker;

Comment: No its working fine in html page.But dont know why it is not working in jsfiddle.

Comment: I have added all the neccessary links on external resources tab on jsfiddle.Then also fidlle no loading the google map.But the code in html loads the google map. Please help me. I will upvote for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create a new `oms`-instance for each marker, use the same instance for all markers instead:

[**http://jsfiddle.net/5VFeJ/**](http://jsfiddle.net/5VFeJ/)

Comment: Thanks a lot.I have updated the http://jsfiddle.net/5VFeJ/ link to ask one more doubt.How can i change onclick event to mouse over event to display multiple markers on same location?? Please help

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, for me in http://jsfiddle.net/5VFeJ/ the  mouseover already works.

Answer (score 0):

Google map developer api provide clustering method to see overlapped markers and its contents. Refer to [this link](http://developers.google.com/maps/articles/toomanymarkers?hl=en), or else use [OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier](https://github.com/jawj/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier).